# Ionic Navigating from nav-button added to nav-bar

Tags: ionic-framework

Using the Ionic tabs and nav demo I have been building a simple app.

Here is codepen of example I have been using as a template to follow:
http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/odqCz

In my app I want to add info button to the nav bar, this can be 'secondary' (right) to not interfere with the back button that appears on the left when navigating through the stack.

Here is the /template for one of the tabbed pages that I have added an info button:

```
<ion-view view-title="Gallery">
```

```
  </button>
</ion-nav-buttons>

    <ion-content class="padding">
      <h3>Digit2Widgets Gallery Showcase.</h3>
      <p>
        <a class="button button-block button-light" href="#/tab/Demo1">Gallery Demo 1</a>
        <a class="button button-block button-light" href="#/tab/galleryDemo2">Gallery Demo 2</a>
      </p>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
```

Now the gallery demo button bellow works and navigates to demo1 but the button at the top added to nav bar does not, even though they are structured in the same fashion? How can I fix this?
is there an easier way to add a permanent info button to the right of the nav bar?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Fred

Answer (score 0):

I have actually got the answer now:

When adding buttons to Nav You should use ui-sref to navigate by passing the state name:

```
<button class="button button-icon icon ion-ios-information-outline" ui-sref="tab.Demo1">
```

:)